# Is there hava a cloud service to support Image Feature Recogition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-app-engine, azure-mobile-services

I want to implement a feature that you can scan an image of reality by your phone, you will generate a feature code from the image, and then upload it to cloud service. If the database of cloud service has this code, you can download something related to the image. Now, the main problem with me, I need a system or cloud service to help me to identify the images, I don't want to do too much things, so is there hava an existing cloud service to support me do that? Free or paid are ok.

Comment: Questions asking for tool/library recommendations are unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow. Plus, you tagged a bunch of clouds (and a service within one of those clouds), and the question isn't specific to any of these clouds.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Please do not remove the [tag:amazon] tag from questions that should be closed during burnination clean-up. Instead, vote to close them.

Comment: @TylerH What makes you think that this question should be closed?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It is asking for tool recommendations, which is an off-topic request. See bullet point #3 at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*"

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has launched recently a new set of machine-learning APIs called "Project Oxford" that include functionality for face detection and recognition, speech recognition and synthesis, vision and understanding of natural languages

Face APIs provide state-of-the-art algorithms to process face images, like face detection with gender and age prediction, recognition, alignment and other application level features. For more information, see Project Oxford at www.projectoxford.ai/face.

Related Link http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/partners/faceapis/faceapis/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/989752/Integrate-Windows-Azure-Face-APIs-in-a-Cplusplus-a